# Using mock.patch.object with "new" parameter

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am currently using unittest and unittest.mock to test my code. For example, when I want to overwrite a certain method's behaviour I do it as following:

```
def mock_get(address):
   class Response():
       def __init__(self):
           self.status_code = 200
       def json(self):
           dict= {"key":value}
           return json.dumps(dict)
        r = Response()
        return r
with mock.patch.object(requests, 'get', new=mock_get) as get: 
    #call function that uses requests.get
    get.assert_called_with(address)#this throws an exception saying that a function() type does not have an attribute called "assert_called_with"
```

In this example, the same could be achieved without the "new" parameter, however there are cases where I want to write a new function to replace the original one, yet be able to access the mock instance like you would when you patch a function without the "new" parameter like this:

```
with mock.patch("path.to.requests.get") as get:
    get.status_code = 200
    get.json.return_value = {"test_key": "test_value"}
    # call function that uses requests.get
    get.assert_called_with(address)#this works
```

Comment: `mock_get` doesn't return the class (or more importantly, an *instance* of that class) you have defined. Your indentation is off.

Comment: It's unlikely you need to (re)define `Response`; just return a hard-coded instance of `requests.Response` from `mock_get`.